ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes
I get this error when I navigate from initial screen to languageSelection screen and I tried everything but I have no idea why, I tried to use "useNavigation" but it still gave errors so I sstuck to this method instead the app basically should basically route from the initial screen to the languageselection screen using the appnavigator:
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes
here is the code I have for the initial screen :
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Image, ImageStyle, TextStyle, View, ViewStyle, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Text } from "../components";
import { AppStackScreenProps } from "../navigators/AppNavigator";
import { colors, spacing, typography } from "../theme";
import { useNavigation } from "expo-router";

const whiteCloudImage = require("../../assets/images/white-cloud.png");
const skylineImage = require("../../assets/images/skyline.png");

interface InitialScreenProps extends AppStackScreenProps<"Initial"> { }

export const InitialScreen: FC<InitialScreenProps> = observer(function InitialScreen({ navigation }) {
  const navigateToAuth = () => {
    navigation.navigate("LanguageSelection");
  };


  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={$safeArea} onPress={navigateToAuth}>
      <View style={$topContainer}>
        <Image source={whiteCloudImage} style={$firstCloudImage} resizeMode="contain" />
        <Image source={whiteCloudImage} style={$secondCloudImage} resizeMode="contain" />
      </View>
      <View style={$container}>
        <View style={$centerContainer}>
          <Text style={$brandName}>likwid</Text>
          <Text style={$slogan}>Building relationships</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={$bottomContainer}>
        <Image source={skylineImage} style={$bottomImage} resizeMode="cover" />
        <Text style={$version}>Version 1.0</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});

const $safeArea: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: colors.background,
};

const $topContainer: ViewStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  zIndex: 10,
};

const $firstCloudImage: ImageStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: 30,
  left: 16,
  width: "55%",
  height: undefined,
  aspectRatio: 1,
};

const $secondCloudImage: ImageStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: 80,
  left: 250,
  width: "50%",
  height: undefined,
  aspectRatio: 1,
};

const $container: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  width: "100%",
};

const $centerContainer: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: spacing.md,
};

const $bottomContainer: ViewStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: 0,
  width: "100%",
  alignItems: "center",
};

const $bottomImage: ImageStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: 200,
};

const $brandName: TextStyle = {
  color: "#FFD43B",
  fontSize: 48,
  fontWeight: "bold",
  lineHeight: 58,
  fontFamily: typography.bold.normal,
};

const $slogan: TextStyle = {
  color: "#4A483B",
  fontSize: 24,
  fontFamily: typography.openSans.bold,
};

const $version: TextStyle = {
  color: "#4A483B",
  fontSize: 16,
  zIndex: 1,
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: 10,
}; 

code for LanguageSelection screen :
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React, { FC } from "react";
import {
  ImageStyle,
  TextStyle,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  ViewStyle,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { Text } from "../../components";
import { AppStackScreenProps } from "../../navigators";
import { colors, typography } from "../../theme";
import LanguageSelector from "../../components/LanguageSelectorButtont";
import { ArrowLeftIcon } from "../../components/icons";

interface LanguageSelectionScreenProps extends AppStackScreenProps<"LanguageSelection"> { }

export const LanguageSelectionScreen: FC<LanguageSelectionScreenProps> = observer(
  function LanguageSelectionScreen({ navigation }) {
    const navigateToCreateAccount = () => {
      navigation.navigate("Welcome");
    };
    const navigateBack = () => {
      navigation.navigate("Initial");
    };
    const handleLanguageChange = () => { };

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={$safeArea}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateBack} style={$backButton}>
          <ArrowLeftIcon />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={$container}>
          <View style={$contentWrapper}>
            <View style={$centerContainer}>
              <Text style={$welcomeText}>Welcome to</Text>
              {/* <Text style={$welcomeText} tx="selectAuthScreen.welcomeText" /> */}
              <Text text=" " />
              <Text style={$brandName}>likwid</Text>
              {/* <Text style={$brandName} tx="initialScreen.brandName" /> */}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={$textContainer}>
            <View
              style={{
                marginBottom: 20,
              }}
            >
              <Text style={$subText}>Please select your language</Text>
              {/* <Text style={$subText} tx="languageSelectionScreen.selectText" /> */}
            </View>
            <LanguageSelector onPress={handleLanguageChange} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={$bottomContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={$buttonBlueBackground} onPress={navigateToCreateAccount}>
            <Text style={$buttonTextWhite}>Continue</Text>
            {/* <Text style={$buttonTextWhite} tx="languageSelectionScreen.continue" /> */}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
);

const $safeArea: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: colors.background,
};
const $backButton: ViewStyle = {
  alignSelf: "flex-start",
  marginLeft: 20,
  marginBottom: 50,
};
const $container: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "flex-start",
  alignItems: "center",
  width: "100%",
  marginTop: 80,
};

const $contentWrapper: ViewStyle = {
  alignItems: "center",
};

const $centerContainer: ViewStyle = {
  flexDirection: "row",
  alignItems: "baseline",
};

const $firstCloudImage: ImageStyle = {
  width: "50%",
  height: undefined,
  aspectRatio: 1,
  marginTop: 40,
};

const $welcomeText: TextStyle = {
  color: "#4A483B",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontFamily: typography.openSans.regular,
  fontSize: 32,
  fontStyle: "normal",
  fontWeight: "700",
  lineHeight: 68,
};

const $textContainer: ViewStyle = {
  alignItems: "center",
  marginTop: 120,
};

const $subText: TextStyle = {
  color: "#B3B3B3",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontFamily: typography.dmSans.regular,
  fontSize: 16,
  fontStyle: "normal",
  fontWeight: "500",
  lineHeight: 22,
  letterSpacing: 0.02,
};

const $brandName: TextStyle = {
  color: "#FFD43B",
  fontFamily: typography.bold.normal,
  fontSize: 32,
  fontStyle: "normal",
  fontWeight: "400",
  lineHeight: 58,
};

const $bottomContainer: ViewStyle = {
  paddingBottom: 20,
};

const $buttonWhiteBackground: ViewStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  paddingVertical: 7.5,
  paddingHorizontal: 15,
  borderRadius: 25,
  alignItems: "center",
  marginBottom: 10,
  width: 240,
  alignSelf: "center",
  shadowColor: "#000",
  shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
  shadowOpacity: 0.25,
  shadowRadius: 2,
  elevation: 5,
};

const $buttonBlueBackground: ViewStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "#007bff",
  paddingVertical: 7.5,
  paddingHorizontal: 15,
  borderRadius: 25,
  alignItems: "center",
  width: 240,
  alignSelf: "center",
};

const $buttonTextBlue: TextStyle = {
  color: "#007bff",
  fontSize: 16,
  fontWeight: "bold",
};

const $buttonTextWhite: TextStyle = {
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  fontSize: 16,
  fontWeight: "bold",
};


AppNavigator.tsx :
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  NavigationContainer,
  NavigatorScreenParams,
  RouteProp,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import * as Screens from "../screens";
import Config from "../config";
import { useStores } from "../models";
import { HomeNavigator, HomeTabParamList } from "./HomeNavigator";
import { navigationRef, useBackButtonHandler } from "./navigationUtilities";
import { colors } from "../theme";
import { ManagerNavigator } from "./ManagerNavigator";
import { BasicNavigator } from "./BasicNavigator";
import { CustomerNavigator } from "./CustomerNavigator";
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from "react-native-screens/lib/typescript/native-stack/types";

export type AppStackParamList = {
  Welcome: undefined;
  Initial: undefined;
  SelectAuth: undefined;
  CreateAccount: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  CustomerLogin: undefined;
  Register: undefined;
  CustomerRegister: undefined;
  MerchantRegister: undefined;
  Home: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeTabParamList>;
  Launch: undefined;
  LanguageSelection: undefined;
  MemberLogin: undefined;
  SelectAccountLogin: undefined;
  AccountSetup: undefined;
};

const exitRoutes = Config.exitRoutes;

export type AppStackScreenProps<T extends keyof AppStackParamList> = {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<AppStackParamList, T>;
  route: RouteProp<AppStackParamList, T>;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppStackParamList>();

const AppStack = observer(function AppStack() {
  const {
    authenticationStore: { isAuthenticated, authRole },
  } = useStores();

  const RenderNavigator = () => {
    switch (authRole) {
      case "Retailer":
        return <HomeNavigator />;
      case "Manager":
        return <ManagerNavigator />;
      case "Basic":
        return <BasicNavigator />;
      case "User":
        return <CustomerNavigator />;
      default:
        return <HomeNavigator />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>

      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, navigationBarColor: colors.background }}
        initialRouteName={isAuthenticated ? "Home" : "Initial"}
      >
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={RenderNavigator} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Screens.LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="CustomerLogin" component={Screens.CustomerLoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Screens.RegisterScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="CustomerRegister" component={Screens.CustomerRegisterScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="MerchantRegister" component={Screens.MerchantRegisterScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="MemberLogin" component={Screens.MemberLoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Initial" component={Screens.InitialScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Screens.WelcomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="LanguageSelection" component={Screens.LanguageSelectionScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SelectAuth" component={Screens.SelectAuthScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Launch" component={Screens.LaunchScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="CreateAccount" component={Screens.CreateAccountScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SelectAccountLogin" component={Screens.SelectAccountLoginScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
});

export interface NavigationProps
  extends Partial<React.ComponentProps<typeof NavigationContainer>> { }

export const AppNavigator = observer(function AppNavigator(props: NavigationProps) {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  useBackButtonHandler((routeName) => exitRoutes.includes(routeName));

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      theme={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
      {...props}
    >
      <AppStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
});


